# Monotorrent parts are inaccessible due to their protection level

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, monotorrent

This is obviously newbie question so please bear with me.

While trying to compile an example supplied with mono-torrent:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using MonoTorrent;
using MonoTorrent.Common;
using MonoTorrent.Client;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using MonoTorrent.BEncoding;
using MonoTorrent.Client.Encryption;
using MonoTorrent.Client.Tracker;
using MonoTorrent.Dht;
using MonoTorrent.Dht.Listeners;

namespace MonoTorrent
{
    class main
    {
        static string dhtNodeFile;
        static string basePath;
        static string downloadsPath;
        static string fastResumeFile;
        static string torrentsPath;
        static ClientEngine engine;             // The engine used for downloading
        static List<TorrentManager> torrents;   // The list where all the torrentManagers will be stored that the engine gives us
        static Top10Listener listener;          // This is a subclass of TraceListener which remembers the last 20 statements sent to it

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* Generate the paths to the folder we will save .torrent files to and where we download files to */
            basePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;                        // This is the directory we are currently in
            torrentsPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "Torrents");              // This is the directory we will save .torrents to
            downloadsPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "Downloads");            // This is the directory we will save downloads to
            fastResumeFile = Path.Combine(torrentsPath, "fastresume.data");
            dhtNodeFile = Path.Combine(basePath, "DhtNodes");
            torrents = new List<TorrentManager>();                          // This is where we will store the torrentmanagers
            listener = new Top10Listener(10);

            // We need to cleanup correctly when the user closes the window by using ctrl-c
            // or an unhandled exception happens
            Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate { shutdown(); };
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += delegate { shutdown(); };
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += delegate(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject); shutdown(); };
            Thread.GetDomain().UnhandledException += delegate(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject); shutdown(); };

            StartEngine();
        }

        private static void StartEngine()
        {
            int port;
            Torrent torrent = null;
            // Ask the user what port they want to use for incoming connections
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + "Choose a listen port: ");
            while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out port)) { }



            // Create the settings which the engine will use
            // downloadsPath - this is the path where we will save all the files to
            // port - this is the port we listen for connections on
            EngineSettings engineSettings = new EngineSettings(downloadsPath, port);
            engineSettings.PreferEncryption = false;
            engineSettings.AllowedEncryption = EncryptionTypes.All;

            //engineSettings.GlobalMaxUploadSpeed = 30 * 1024;
            //engineSettings.GlobalMaxDownloadSpeed = 100 * 1024;
            //engineSettings.MaxReadRate = 1 * 1024 * 1024;


            // Create the default settings which a torrent will have.
            // 4 Upload slots - a good ratio is one slot per 5kB of upload speed
            // 50 open connections - should never really need to be changed
            // Unlimited download speed - valid range from 0 -> int.Max
            // Unlimited upload speed - valid range from 0 -> int.Max
            TorrentSettings torrentDefaults = new TorrentSettings(4, 150, 0, 0);

            // Create an instance of the engine.
            engine = new ClientEngine(engineSettings);
            engine.ChangeListenEndpoint(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
            byte[] nodes = null;
            try
            {
                nodes = File.ReadAllBytes(dhtNodeFile);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No existing dht nodes could be loaded");
            }

            DhtListener dhtListner = new DhtListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
            DhtEngine dht = new DhtEngine(dhtListner);
            engine.RegisterDht(dht);
            dhtListner.Start();
            engine.DhtEngine.Start(nodes);

            // If the SavePath does not exist, we want to create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(engine.Settings.SavePath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(engine.Settings.SavePath);

            // If the torrentsPath does not exist, we want to create it
            if (!Directory.Exists(torrentsPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(torrentsPath);

            BEncodedDictionary fastResume;
            try
            {
                fastResume = BEncodedValue.Decode<BEncodedDictionary>(File.ReadAllBytes(fastResumeFile));
            }
            catch
            {
                fastResume = new BEncodedDictionary();
            }

            // For each file in the torrents path that is a .torrent file, load it into the engine.
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(torrentsPath))
            {
                if (file.EndsWith(".torrent"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Load the .torrent from the file into a Torrent instance
                        // You can use this to do preprocessing should you need to
                        torrent = Torrent.Load(file);
                        Console.WriteLine(torrent.InfoHash.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Couldn't decode {0}: ", file);
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        continue;
                    }
                    // When any preprocessing has been completed, you create a TorrentManager
                    // which you then register with the engine.
                    TorrentManager manager = new TorrentManager(torrent, downloadsPath, torrentDefaults);
                    if (fastResume.ContainsKey(torrent.InfoHash.ToHex()))
                        manager.LoadFastResume(new FastResume((BEncodedDictionary)fastResume[torrent.infoHash.ToHex()]));
                    engine.Register(manager);

                    // Store the torrent manager in our list so we can access it later
                    torrents.Add(manager);
                    manager.PeersFound += new EventHandler<PeersAddedEventArgs>(manager_PeersFound);
                }
            }

            // If we loaded no torrents, just exist. The user can put files in the torrents directory and start
            // the client again
            if (torrents.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No torrents found in the Torrents directory");
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
                engine.Dispose();
                return;
            }

            // For each torrent manager we loaded and stored in our list, hook into the events
            // in the torrent manager and start the engine.
            foreach (TorrentManager manager in torrents)
            {
                // Every time a piece is hashed, this is fired.
                manager.PieceHashed += delegate(object o, PieceHashedEventArgs e)
                {
                    lock (listener)
                        listener.WriteLine(string.Format("Piece Hashed: {0} - {1}", e.PieceIndex, e.HashPassed ? "Pass" : "Fail"));
                };

                // Every time the state changes (Stopped -> Seeding -> Downloading -> Hashing) this is fired
                manager.TorrentStateChanged += delegate(object o, TorrentStateChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    lock (listener)
                        listener.WriteLine("OldState: " + e.OldState.ToString() + " NewState: " + e.NewState.ToString());
                };

                // Every time the tracker's state changes, this is fired
                foreach (TrackerTier tier in manager.TrackerManager)
                {
                    foreach (MonoTorrent.Client.Tracker.Tracker t in tier.Trackers)
                    {
                        t.AnnounceComplete += delegate(object sender, AnnounceResponseEventArgs e)
                        {
                            listener.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", e.Successful, e.Tracker.ToString()));
                        };
                    }
                }
                // Start the torrentmanager. The file will then hash (if required) and begin downloading/seeding
                manager.Start();
            }

            // While the torrents are still running, print out some stats to the screen.
            // Details for all the loaded torrent managers are shown.
            int i = 0;
            bool running = true;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
            while (running)
            {
                if ((i++) % 10 == 0)
                {
                    sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
                    running = torrents.Exists(delegate(TorrentManager m) { return m.State != TorrentState.Stopped; });

                    AppendFormat(sb, "Total Download Rate: {0:0.00}kB/sec", engine.TotalDownloadSpeed / 1024.0);
                    AppendFormat(sb, "Total Upload Rate:   {0:0.00}kB/sec", engine.TotalUploadSpeed / 1024.0);
                    AppendFormat(sb, "Disk Read Rate:      {0:0.00} kB/s", engine.DiskManager.ReadRate / 1024.0);
                    AppendFormat(sb, "Disk Write Rate:     {0:0.00} kB/s", engine.DiskManager.WriteRate / 1024.0);
                    AppendFormat(sb, "Total Read:         {0:0.00} kB", engine.DiskManager.TotalRead / 1024.0);
                    AppendFormat(sb, "Total Written:      {0:0.00} kB", engine.DiskManager.TotalWritten / 1024.0);
                    AppendFormat(sb, "Open Connections:    {0}", engine.ConnectionManager.OpenConnections);

                    foreach (TorrentManager manager in torrents)
                    {
                        AppendSeperator(sb);
                        AppendFormat(sb, "State:           {0}", manager.State);
                        AppendFormat(sb, "Name:            {0}", manager.Torrent == null ? "MetaDataMode" : manager.Torrent.Name);
                        AppendFormat(sb, "Progress:           {0:0.00}", manager.Progress);
                        AppendFormat(sb, "Download Speed:     {0:0.00} kB/s", manager.Monitor.DownloadSpeed / 1024.0);
                        AppendFormat(sb, "Upload Speed:       {0:0.00} kB/s", manager.Monitor.UploadSpeed / 1024.0);
                        AppendFormat(sb, "Total Downloaded:   {0:0.00} MB", manager.Monitor.DataBytesDownloaded / (1024.0 * 1024.0));
                        AppendFormat(sb, "Total Uploaded:     {0:0.00} MB", manager.Monitor.DataBytesUploaded / (1024.0 * 1024.0));
                        MonoTorrent.Client.Tracker.Tracker tracker = manager.TrackerManager.CurrentTracker;
                        //AppendFormat(sb, "Tracker Status:     {0}", tracker == null ? "<no tracker>" : tracker.State.ToString());
                        AppendFormat(sb, "Warning Message:    {0}", tracker == null ? "<no tracker>" : tracker.WarningMessage);
                        AppendFormat(sb, "Failure Message:    {0}", tracker == null ? "<no tracker>" : tracker.FailureMessage);
                        if (manager.PieceManager != null)
                            AppendFormat(sb, "Current Requests:   {0}", manager.PieceManager.CurrentRequestCount());

                        foreach (PeerId p in manager.GetPeers())
                            AppendFormat(sb, "\t{2} - {1:0.00}/{3:0.00}kB/sec - {0}", p.Peer.ConnectionUri,
                                                                                      p.Monitor.DownloadSpeed / 1024.0,
                                                                                      p.AmRequestingPiecesCount,
                                                                                      p.Monitor.UploadSpeed / 1024.0);

                        AppendFormat(sb, "", null);
                        if (manager.Torrent != null)
                            foreach (TorrentFile file in manager.Torrent.Files)
                                AppendFormat(sb, "{1:0.00}% - {0}", file.Path, file.BitField.PercentComplete);
                    }
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                    listener.ExportTo(Console.Out);
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        static void manager_PeersFound(object sender, PeersAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            lock (listener)
                listener.WriteLine(string.Format("Found {0} new peers and {1} existing peers", e.NewPeers, e.ExistingPeers));//throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }

        private static void AppendSeperator(StringBuilder sb)
        {
            AppendFormat(sb, "", null);
            AppendFormat(sb, "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -", null);
            AppendFormat(sb, "", null);
        }
        private static void AppendFormat(StringBuilder sb, string str, params object[] formatting)
        {
            if (formatting != null)
                sb.AppendFormat(str, formatting);
            else
                sb.Append(str);
            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        private static void shutdown()
        {
            BEncodedDictionary fastResume = new BEncodedDictionary();
            for (int i = 0; i < torrents.Count; i++)
            {
                torrents[i].Stop(); ;
                while (torrents[i].State != TorrentState.Stopped)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", torrents[i].Torrent.Name, torrents[i].State);
                    Thread.Sleep(250);
                }

                fastResume.Add(torrents[i].Torrent.InfoHash.ToHex(), torrents[i].SaveFastResume().Encode());
            }

            #if !DISABLE_DHT
            File.WriteAllBytes(dhtNodeFile, engine.DhtEngine.SaveNodes());
            #endif
            File.WriteAllBytes(fastResumeFile, fastResume.Encode());
            engine.Dispose();

            foreach (TraceListener lst in Debug.Listeners)
            {
                lst.Flush();
                lst.Close();
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

I encounter the following:

`MonoTorrent.Common.Torrent.infoHash' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122) (test)

and some more errors like this one. What should I do?
Should I modify monotorrent making some of the properties public (as googling suggests) or there is other way around? 
I don't feel confident enough to mess with monotorrent's internals.

I'm using mono-develop and target is set to Mono /.NET 4 '

Actually I've got five more errors:

/home/ge/lab/test/test/test/Main.cs(75,75): Error CS0122: `MonoTorrent.Client.Tracker.TrackerTier.Trackers' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122) (test)

/home/ge/lab/test/test/test/Main.cs(75,75): Error CS0122: `MonoTorrent.Client.Tracker.TrackerTier.Trackers.get' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122) (test)

/home/ge/lab/test/test/test/Main.cs(94,94): Error CS0122: `MonoTorrent.Client.PieceManager.CurrentRequestCount()' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122) (test)

/home/ge/lab/test/test/test/Main.cs(89,89): Error CS0122: `MonoTorrent.Client.PeerId.Peer' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122) (test)

/home/ge/lab/test/test/test/Main.cs(89,89): Error CS0122: `MonoTorrent.Client.PeerId.Peer.get' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122) (test)

Comment: You have misspelled the public property "InfoHash" and accidentally referred to the internal/private field "infoHash".

Comment: @Tormod that's actually how the sample code is, for better or worse. It works in the sample because the library exposes it's internals to the sample project...

Comment: Well, maybe someone should ask them to change their samples to not use private types.  This pretty much looks like a typo in their sample, tbh.

Comment: It is strange and unexpected, agreed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at AssemblyInfo.cs in the MonoTorrent project, you will see this:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("SampleClient")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MonoTorrent.Tests")]
```

The allows the 'SampleClient' project to access members that have their visibility set to 'internal'.

In your project, you should make sure you are accessing public properties only, not the internal/private fields. For example, you have this line:

```
manager.LoadFastResume(new FastResume((BEncodedDictionary)fastResume[torrent.infoHash.ToHex()]));
```

Which you should be able to change like this:

```
manager.LoadFastResume(new FastResume((BEncodedDictionary)fastResume[torrent.InfoHash.ToHex()]));
```

(Note the casing on the 'InfoHash' property)

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand principle behind the method of fixing this error. I should dig into mono torrent source code and see which method uses which getter/setter or something like that?

Comment: Change the line as indicated in my answer (change 'torrent.infoHash' to 'torrent.InfoHash') and it should work. It's an error in the code; you are calling the internal backing field 'infoHash' rather than the public property 'InfoHash'.

Comment: Yes, but I have 5 more errors like this one. How should I fix them?

Comment: For the remaining errors, you will need to either: comment out those lines, change the MonoTorrent source to make these properties public, or change the MonoTorrent source to expose it's internal variables to your project

Comment: thank you very much. It seems they took a really weired approach to either library design or sample project...

Comment: @Moonwalker Yes, I can't fault the library but the implementation of the sample is very strange

Comment: Using InternalsVisibleTo for the sample client is a bad hack. The library is great, but the interface could do with some rationalization. From the layout, I suspect some of the strangeness comes from the porting process, probably from C given the fondness for declaring variables at the start of functions.